# limit git add . -A -n to present directory (no subdirectories)

Tags: git

How do I limit the output of:

```
git add . -A -n
```

to the present directory only? E.g. something like:

```
git add . -A -n --depth=0
```

I am currently at the base directory of my project and want to see files that are changed at that level only. Using `grep -v` as part of post-processing the output is not practical due to `git add . -A -n` taking too long when it has to scan sub-directories as well.

Comment: `ls -p|grep -v /` is essentially the same as `find . -maxdepth 1 -type f` except that it's shorter. Maybe the slow part is the dot, which is a directory and therefore causes git to recurse into subdirectories. In fact the xargs version below should even be faster, as doesn't need to invoke git for each file, but rather gives one git invocation as many file arguments as it can.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
ls -p|grep -v / |xargs git add -An
```

Answer (score 2):

```
find . -maxdepth 1 \( -type f -o -type l \) -exec git add {} -A -n \;
```